# Set or limit number of connections a single pymongo client will open

Tags: mongodb, python

Is there a way to set or limit the number of connections to Mongo a single pymongo client instance will open? I don't want to modify Mongo config to do this, because I don't want to affect other applications.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following parameter to set the number of maximum connections from your pymongo app.

```
client = MongoClient(host, port, maxPoolSize=10)
```

Here is [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo) with more details.

Comment: Says pool size is number of Mongo operations allowed. Does this always equate to number of network connections? Network is my bottleneck, with many active connections depending on scaling